# php sanitize form input with function

Tags: php, forms, function, input, sanitize

Is this the correct way to set a function to check for empty spaces, special characters and remove them?

```
               function sanitizeData($data)
                {

                    $data = htmlspecialchars($data); 
                    $data = stripslashes($data);
                    $data = trim($data);                        
                    return $data;
                }
```

Is this the correct method of applying the function?

```
 $complex = sanitizeData($_POST['complex']);
```

Comment: no. it's not. if you're doing this for SQL injection prevention, then it's essentially useless. specialchars does **NOT** convert `'` quotes by default.

Comment: That's just a garbage function that gets passed around in a dozen variations without relevant comments. Where did you copy it from?

Comment: @mario I did  not copy it from anywhere. This is for a submission form. It is a long form.

Answer (score -1):

This is the easy way out in PHP there is also a  Object oriented way if you are into it.

```
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
    $city = "'s Hertogenbosch"; //your input string.
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $city);
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT into myCity (Name) VALUES ('$city')")
```

Fix for copy and paste:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
function sanitized($variable){
  $variable = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $variable);
} //variables have been sanitized!

mysqli_query($link, "INSERT into myCity (Name) VALUES ('$city')")
```

Heck you could loop for each value in the $_POST or $_GET array and just apply the function. sorry for the many edits, kinda rusty on the php side.

Comment: I have too many inputs and this would make for messy coding. I already have this, trying to minimize.

Comment: I strongly think problem of SQL injection is not..."sanatization". Simply: **user input  should not be used to build a SQL command**. Dot. Use query parameters. Dot. `mysqli_real_escape_string` and friends are a pretty nice way to have a **false sense of security**, they **mess up your code** and you're safe only from legitimate users (or a "poor man hacker"). What if it enters **SQL text in a numeric field**? What if an hacker posts this **skipping client side validation**? No quotes to strip there. What if he adds a new argument and he **forgets to escape it**? What if he has 20 parameters?